# How to move Active Directory Settings on a Winodws Server 2016 to another server that has Windows Server 2019 that Does not have A.D

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2016, domain-controller, windows-server-2019

How to move Active Directory Settings on a Windows Server 2016 to another server that has Windows Server 2019 that Does not have A.D

To clarify further I have a Windows Server 2016 with DNS setup, and a Domain Controller Active Directory Services setup on one Server.

However I want to move the Settings from the Windows Server 2016 to my newer server which is on different hardware. The newer server setup is Windows Server 2019 and I only have the defaults setup for Windows Server 2019 Active Directory and Domain Controller are not setup.

Is there anyway to get DNS settings and Active Directory Domain Controller onto my newer server Windows Server 2019 using some sort of settings file or importing method?
Any advice would be helpful. I am willing to setup DNS and AD DC  services on windows server 2019 and If that is the route I have to take then okay I will do it, but preferably if there is an easier way to use a settings file to copy what I have on WS 2016 to WS 2019 I'd much prefer that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "settings" you mean AD and DNS then no, there isn't any "import" method. You'll need to install the AD DS and DNS roles on the new server and promote it to a Domain Controller.